# Houseplant with clustered red berries at the bottom part of the plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I bought a plant but the seller does not know the scientific name of the plant. He says that it is a money tree, but can't seem to find a money tree that fits the description on the Internet.

It has clusters of orange-red berries around the bottom part of the plant and elongated dark green leaves.

Whole Plant Picture:

[image]

Fruits or Berries:

[image]

Leaves:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plant is [Ardisia crenata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ardisia_crenata), a member of the primrose family that is native to East Asia. It has a variety of common names such as coralberry, coral ardisia, spiceberry, Christmas berry. It is an upright perennial shrub that can grow six feet (2 Meter) tall outside but will remain smaller indoors. Strong diffuse light and moist soil are required.

It is considered an [invasive plant in Florida](http://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/ag281), Hawaii and Australia.

There are conflicting reports of toxicity for this plant.  It appears the leaves and berries can be toxic. Another [site](http://www.pfaf.org/user/Plant.aspx?LatinName=Ardisia%20crenata) indicates it promotes blood circulation.